# Display email template in VF Page?

Tags: email-template, css

I'm trying to display an email template in VF Page using `inputTextArea`. But indenting is getting messed up. Do I have to use CSS for this or am I missing something silly? Some weird gray bar is also showing up.

[image: This is how it looks in the console subtab]

This is the template:
[image]

And the VF Page snippet in the comment:

```
<apex:inputTextarea value="{!emailBody}" richText="true" rows="25"/>
```

Comment: This is the VF Page:
<apex:inputTextarea value="{!emailBody}" richText="true" rows="25"/>

Comment: Is this in lightning? console?

Comment: @javanoob console.